# Dynamic String Compile

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there an easy way to do a one time template string compile/one way data bind? I do not need dynamic components just something that would process template string e.g.`My name is {{person.name}}` and bind a supplied context e.g. `{name: 'John'}`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this is exactly what I do not want to do - create new module, create dynamic component, etc This is an overkill for a simple task that I want to achieve.

Comment: I don't think it will change a lot if you want that or not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [babeljs](/questions/tagged/babeljs) or similar (or specific [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility)) you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this:

```js
var person = { name: 'john' };
var result = `My name is ${person.name}`;

console.log(result);
```

If not, you can use a regex like this:

```js
var person = { name: 'john' };
var result = 'My name is {{person.name}}'.replace(/{{?.*}}/, function(a) {
  return eval(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

Of course that it's dummy demo but this is the principal.